# Run JS with imacros in terminal

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I created a javascript imacros file that runs fine in browser with firefox.
But I want to run the script in command line. How can I do this?

I'm trying to do this way:

```
open -a Firefox "/Users/.../iMacros/Macros/test.js"
```

But this way the firefox page is opened and the js file is open also. But the script doesn't run.

Is there a way to run the script without firefox window open? Just on command line I mean. I'm using OS X.

Comment: Can you post the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
open -a Firefox "imacros://run/?m=test.js"
```

See http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Command_Line_Support